# Scripts directory is missing from Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-venv, pyvenv

[image: There is no directory call Scripts]

There is no directory called `Scripts`. How can I activate?

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What's in `bin`?  How did you create this virtual environment?  `py -m venv myvenv` gives me `Scripts` instead of `bin` on Windows.

Comment: inside bin there is activate file. But I don't know how to actuvate. What command should I use?

Comment: How about "activate" 

Answer (score 4):

Check the line **"Home"** in `pyvenv.cfg`, it can differ from your python interpreter location. In my case it was `home = C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, so this caused another project structure without the **"Scripts"** directory.

You can configure interpreter location in PATH variables and try to create a virtual environment again.

Comment: This helped me track down the problem. After a quick uninstall/reinstall, all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check bin folder, to activate Virtual environment, theres should be a script under it

you can simply use cmd to activate it by following command

> .\Activate

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 py -m venv env
```

instead of

```
python -m venv env
```

when creating the virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but after lots of research, i found some outcomes which i want to share with you...
Please follow my steps sequentially:

1. **python3 -V**  // *check the version of python like 3.8.1*
2. **sudo apt install python3-venv** // *for installing the latest virtual environment library*
3. **python3 -m venv my-project-env** //create virtual environment, where you can change name of **my-project-env** into your requirement name..
4. **source my-project-env/bin/activate** // activate your evnironment

**NOTE**: point no-4, please add ***source*** word in your command while run point no 4 commands on your terminal.

please refer to my attachment pic ...

[image]